# Image procssing - What are kernel space, functions and data?

Tags: image-processing, locality-sensitive-hash

I'm reading [Kernelized Locality-Sensitive Hashing](http://people.bu.edu/bkulis/pubs/iccv_klsh.pdf), which is obviously based on the concept of kernel applied to space, functions and data.

I'm not confident with this concept in math and image processing too (since it's not my domain, sorry if I'm naive), so please can someone help me to understand it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an exhaustive and simple article about what kernel functions are in this [article](http://www.eric-kim.net/eric-kim-net/posts/1/kernel_trick.html.) (that I strongly suggest).